# Binding Values To PreparedStatement without knowing the data types

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

Binding the values to preparedstatement using setObject(index,object) worked fine using MySQL but not with Oracle.

```
preparedStatement.setObject(i, bindValue);
```

Below is the query built after appending the bind variables.

```
select ACC_NO from ACC_TABLE where ACC_NAME='java.lang.String';
```

It is trying to convert to `java.lang.String` type, which results in the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not execute sql command - Original message: null

Whereas my ACC_NAME is 'user01'.

So actually the query should be some thing like this,

```
select ACC_NO from ACC_TABLE where ACC_NAME='user01';
```

So, if my understanding is not wrong, `preparedStatement.setObject(index, object)` is converting the data to its respective data type and setting it.

`preparedStatement.setObject(index, object)` in MySQL is working perfectly alright with no issues.

Only problem is while using Oracle.

The Oracle DB version i am working with is:

> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production "CORE  11.2.0.2.0  Production"
>   TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production NLSRTL Version
>   11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception and add some formatting (eg code formatting) to your question.

Comment: Are you sure that `bindValue` contains 'user01' ? what happens when you try `preparedStatement.setObject(i, 'user01');` ?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : Sure will do it from now on and thanks for formatting it.

Comment: @A.B.Cade Yes the variable bindValue has value 'user01'.

Comment: Have you looked at [`getParameterMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData()) that should help you decide on the type (specifically [`getParameterType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html#getParameterType(int)))

Comment: `p_parameterMetaData.getParameterCount()` Resulted the parameter count i.e '1' in my case but `p_parameterMetaData.getParameterType(i)` threw         java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterType(OracleParameterMetaData.java:166)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but...

The method setObject(index, Object) may be used to pass datatabase- specific abstract data types, by using a driver-specific Java type. If the object is of a class implementing the interface SQLData, the JDBC driver should call the method SQLData.writeSQL to write it to the SQL data stream. If, on the other hand, the object is of a class implementing Ref, Blob, Clob, NClob, Struct, java.net.URL, RowId, SQLXML or Array, the driver should pass it to the database as a value of the corresponding SQL type. --- Collected from Java Docs

Comment: @user245830: `setObject(1, "user01")` in this case it is not an object of any type, it is just a primitive of type string. I am trying to use `setObject(index, Object)` when i don't know the data type of the object being passed. For example, setString(index, String) is used for datatype String, setInt(index, int) is used for data type int, but i don't the datatype so trying to use `setObject(index, Object)` which sets the DataType _'java.lang.String'_ as its value for which the resultset is empty. Sample query generated is below `select ACC_NO from ACC_TABLE where ACC_NAME='java.lang.String';`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below parameters,

preparedStatement.setString(index, value)
Ex:
preparedStatement.setString(1, 'user01')